# Listview scrolling bug on 5.1

Tags: android, listview, android-5.0-lollipop

Just noticed a very weird bug in ListView, seems reproducible only 5.1, and I really wonder how nobody brought it up already (couldn't find anything related).

Pretty easy to reproduce :

Find a ListView with enough items (100 +) , scroll somewhere to the 3/4 of the list , now scroll up fast (2-3 long flings) , you'll notice the ListView scroll all the way to the bottom!

P.S don't try to blame it on my code since I managed to reproduce it on Contacts/FB/Google IO/Whatsapp...

Now IMO this is pretty severe bug, and I would like to find a workaround/fix ASAP, so anyone got one ?

Update : `ListView.java` hasn't changed from SDK21, but `AbsListView.java` did.

Comment: I can confirm. You'll probably want to file a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).

Comment: @NiekHaarman , already reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?q=scroll%205.1&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=159739)

Comment: Nice, hadn't found that one.

Comment: This is also happened with me. Contacts and other google apps also has same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may use recycler view instead of list view as it may no longer be supported by Google. Try the slidenerd videos on YouTube. It will help you with it. Hope it helps.